# Is there a fast way to create a numpy array that reduces unique values to their lowest form?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Sorry if the question is worded confusingly. I have an array similar to the following:
`[[3,7,9,5],[3,3,7,5]]`, though much larger.

How can I convert this into a form such as`[[0,2,3,1],[0,0,2,1]]` where each unique value starting with the lowest is given an identifying number, starting with 0? Currently I am using a for loop, but it is very slow. Is there any functions in numpy that could speed this up?

Comment: So, you have an array of lists, because it seems they have variable number of elements per list?

Comment: Also, do you want to find the minimal element of each list or the minimal value of all lists and normalize the whole array. Your example is somewhat bad, as it does not show this explicitly.

Comment: Also, are the lists of variable lengths?

Comment: Sorry! I'm on mobile, didn't realize I typed an extra element. The array is a square 2100x2100 array of integers , not an array of lists.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 5):

We can use one approach using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional arg `return_inverse` set as `True`. This flattens the input when fed to it, giving us unique IDs in sequence starting from `0`. The uniqueness is maintained across all elements in the array because it was flattened. So, the output needs a reshape afterwards to bring it back to the same shape as the input.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [208]: a = np.array([[3,7,9,5],[3,3,7,5]])

In [209]: np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape)
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 2, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Your answer does not work *always*. For example let `a=[[1,2],[3,4,5,0]]` then the answer I get is `[[0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 0, 2, 1, 3]]`

Comment: @AGNGazer Hmm really? I get : `[[0, 1], [1, 2, 3, 0]]`. Are you sure you are using your `a` and not OP's `a`?

Comment: Ah, a silly copy (from wrong line)/paste mistake. Indeed, I get `[[0, 1], [1, 2, 3, 0]]` too. However, I would have expected `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 0]]` if I understood the question correctly. That is, I think `unique()` needs to be run on the flattened list.

Comment: @AGNGazer With a regular array  (as OP indicated he/she is working with in their edits), `np.unique(a, return_inverse=1)[1]` flattens it and thus achieves the global tagging as you mentioned. Check out the edits.

Comment: Yes, your last edit and this comment from OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199104/is-there-a-fast-way-to-create-a-numpy-array-that-reduces-unique-values-to-their/45199161?noredirect=1#comment77366134_45199104 makes your code do what is needed.